# Apache Chemistry openCMIS session taking too long

Tags: session, amazon-web-services, alfresco, bitnami, opencmis

I am trying to connect to Alfresco using openCMIS and it is taking 6-18 seconds to get a session object. My code is as follows.

```java
private static String ALFRESCO_ATOMPUB_URL = "http://localhost/alfresco/service/cmis";
public Session getAtomSession() {

    long time1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    SessionFactory sessionFactory = SessionFactoryImpl.newInstance();
    Map<String, String> parameter = new HashMap<String, String>();
    parameter.put(SessionParameter.USER, SYSTEM_USER);
    parameter.put(SessionParameter.PASSWORD, SYSTEM_PASSWORD);
    parameter.put(SessionParameter.BINDING_TYPE, BindingType.ATOMPUB.value());
    parameter.put(SessionParameter.ATOMPUB_URL, ALFRESCO_ATOMPUB_URL);
    parameter.put(SessionParameter.AUTH_HTTP_BASIC, "true" );
    parameter.put(SessionParameter.COOKIES, "true" );

    /*
    List<Repository> repositories = new ArrayList<Repository>();
    repositories = sessionFactory.getRepositories(parameter);

    Repository repository = repositories.get(0);
    log.debug("REPOSITORY_ID: "+repository.getId());*/
    parameter.put(SessionParameter.REPOSITORY_ID, MY_REPOSITORY_ID);


    Session session = sessionFactory.createSession(parameter);

    //log.debug("Got a connection to repository: " + repository.getName() + ", with id: " + repository.getId());
    long time2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long difftime = time2 - time1;
    log.debug("Time Taken for Atom Session: "+difftime+" ms.");
    return session;
}
```

I tried without cookies and without AUTH_HTTP_BASIC but no success. I am running a bitNami Alfresco 4.0.e-0 instance and hosting my app along with Alfresco in same tomcat 6 server. I am new to coding with Alfresco, so cannot fathom what i should be doing to prevent the long time to get session object. Can anyone please let me know if i am doing something wrong or if i can overcome this problem? Much Appreciated!

Comment: Can you not just get the session object and cache it, to avoid re-fetching? The session has a lot of info on it that'll need to be generated / serialized / de-serialized, hence the timings

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I can do that but it is for the first fetch that is taking lot of time.

Comment: Are you sure there's nothing else going on that's wrong, such as dns timeouts, firewalls, broken servers etc? I've just noticed you wrote 6-18 *seconds* not 6-18 *miliseconds*, so your requests are several orders of magnitude slower than they should be...

Comment: It is possible that something else might be the problem too... that is what i wanted to know. There seems to be not much to do with getting session. I'm caching it and reusing it so except the first call for getting session everything else is fast enough. Tried to put call to get session during webapp initialization but that just hangs. As i said  it is a webapp running on same server as Alfresco is running. Should there be DNS timeout issues? Firewall has 80,8443 ports open.

Comment: You are using an outdated CMIS URL. Try http://localhost/alfresco/cmisatom .

Comment: I've used alternate code using CmisBindingFactory to get CmisBinding and from that ObjectService to retrieve objects. This works well and reponse is within 400ms the first time. Should i be using this? or is it limited in anyway? Also, i was advised by Alfresco developers to preferably use Alfresco Webservices client. Where can i find some code for starting off with it?

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
private static String ALFRESCO_ATOMPUB_URL = "http://localhost:8080/alfresco/service/cmis";
```

Comment: Please format code examples with four spaces or a tab before each line... See also: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help